# how to redirect traffic from my server to one ip to another ip address in windows firewall

Tags: windows, security, networking, firewall

Is it possible to redirect the OUTBOUND traffic of my server to one IP to another? For example, one of my applications is trying to send some traffic to an IP address a.b.c.d ip address. But is it possible to send the traffic that application trying to send to a.b.c.d IP address to w.x.y.z IP address through Windows firewall or any other means (but not through the network router or firewall)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The windows firewall only allows rules to be defined that allow outgoing connections to either be allowed (or allowed conditionally) or blocked.

If the application is connecting to the IP directly, you are out of luck. If the application resolves a domain to the IP, you may set it to the w.x.y.z IP in your hosts file.

Otherwise, you are out of luck and will need to use a fully fledged firewall which supports address rewriting in the output chain.

Comment: Thank you 0x90 for strongly confirming the possibility of Windows Firewall feature.

Comment: @0x90, can you list some firewalls, for windows or linux that have this feature?